# Configure tomcat to run python script on Tomcat 7

Tags: python, tomcat

I have a python script which i have to run on tomcat. I have done editing of web.xml file of tomcat with uncommenting the servlet of cgi and servlet mapping. But still on running `http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/`, it gives me error of "Servlet Cgi is not available".
What to do now

Comment: What is the name of your Python script? In what web application (aka "context") has it been deployed? Did you edit Tomcat's `conf/web.xml` (mistake) or did you edit the deployment descriptor of your web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed an online instruction and modified the conf/context.xml file to add in privileged="true" to Context tag as below and it worked.

```
<Context privileged="true">

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->

</Context>
```